# Animating ng-repeat on Remove

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

Consider the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23956/ 
Buttons add and remove work properly and so do their animations. Here is my question: How can I animate elements when button Remove is clicked, so that all elements under the element to be removed will slowly float up and not just jump to their new place? 

When `remove` of B is clicked, I would like to animate C and D to the previous position of B and C, respectfully. 
 
A `remove` 
B `remove` 
C `remove` 
D `remove` 

Solutions using maxheight are not preferable because of the responsive design. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this can be a solution:

```
@keyframes animateIn {
    0%   { opacity: 0; transform: translate(0,-25px);}
    100% { transform: translate(0,0px); }
}
@keyframes animateUp {
    0%   { transform: translate(0,0px); }
    100% { transform: translate(0,-25px);}
}

@keyframes animateOut {
    0%   { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

div.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
div.animate-repeat.ng-enter-active {
    animation: animateIn 0.5s;
}

div.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
div.animate-repeat.ng-leave-active ~ div.animate-repeat{
    animation: animateUp 0.5s;
}
div.animate-repeat.ng-leave-active{
    animation: animateOut,animateUp 0.5s;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7shykff/)

Comment: this is definitely a start, but now all the elements under the removed element first disappear and then reappear. I would like them to just float up. Thanks :)

Comment: check the edit, you can remove the second animateUp to just make the removed element fade instead of move and fade..... better result imho